# d3.js time scale unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created an array of objects inside a for loop. Inside each object i have a key value pair to store time. For achieving this i used a time scale in d3.js. But i am not getting the result as i expected. The code is

```
var xscale = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([new Date(2000, 0, 1), new Date(2000, 0, 2)])
    .domain([0, 288]);

var dataprovider = [];
var ti = 0;
for (var k = 0; k < 288; k++) {
  var t = xscale(ti++);
  dataprovider.push({
    x: t,
    y: Math.random() * 100
  });
}
console.log(dataprovider);
```

the jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/suhailsulu/ujfguoky/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not unexpected: in D3, a time scale has to have the time in the *domain*:

> Time scales are a variant of linear scales that have a **temporal domain**. (emphasis mine)

So, to achieve what you want, you should swap domain and range...

```
var xscale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(2000, 0, 1), new Date(2000, 0, 2)])
    .range([0, 288]);
```

... and then use [invert](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#continuous_invert):

> Given a value from the range, returns the corresponding value from the domain.

Here is a demo:

```js
  var xscale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(2000, 0, 1), new Date(2000, 0, 2)])
    .range([0, 288]);
    
  var dataprovider = [];
  var ti = 0;
  for (var k = 0; k < 288; k++) {
    var t = xscale.invert(ti++);
    dataprovider.push({
      x: t,
      y: Math.random() * 100
    });
  }
  console.log(dataprovider);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked. But when i logged each time inside the loop its showing the correct time. why is it so??  https://jsfiddle.net/suhailsulu/ujfguoky/1/

Comment: @suhailc are you sure? I'm seeing **all** dates equal.

Comment: log inside the loop shows the correct date. But after the loop its changing. When i inverted the scale its working

Comment: Well, I don't know what magic are you doing, but here in my computer the log inside the loop is printing the **same** value 200 times.